# How can I configure Upshot to make partial updates of a ViewModel back to the server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, upshot

I have created a Single Page Application (ASP.NET MVC4) using [Steven Sanderson's instructions](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/03/06/single-page-application-packages-and-samples/). The issue I'm currently seeing is that whenever I edit an item and save the changes, Upshot sends the whole item back to the server and not only the modified properties as it would be expected. (I know this because firebug can inspect what is being sent to the server).

I'm pretty sure that upshot should be able to send only the modified properties as it uses knockout observables so it can keep track of what's changed and what's not.

My question is, is this possible at the moment (maybe some kind of configuration parameter) or should I wait for a future version to implement this? Upshot is a rather new library so finding documentation is pretty hard right now.

Comment: Good question. I would also be interested to know this answer.

Comment: Interesting question, we are waiting for a great answer too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, upshot is only able to submit the entire object to the server. It was designed to work with the SPA `DataController`, whose `Submit` method takes as an input parameter a `ChangeSet` - exactly what upshot sends through the wire. (the original entity, the changed entity and the operation that was performed - e.q. 2 for Update).

However, both *upshot* and the *DataController* have been put on hold by the Microsoft Team, so it might take a while for a new version to appear.

**Update**

You can find the reference [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/358133). They talk about putting the SPA project *"on pause"* for the time being. If you check out the source code, you'll find that *upshot* is a part of the SPA package, and that neither `upshot` nor the `DataController` have been included in the RC release.

Comment: Do you happen to have a reference of this: "both upshot and the DataController have been put on hold by the Micrsofot Team"?

Comment: Updated with the reference :)